# Removing the brackets from an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

So I have an object named `plan_code` which is in the database as a string. However I'm trying to allow for multiple entries to be implemented. I have the user separated these entries by a comma.

I've worked on splitting the integers, but i've run into a problem in that after I split them and display them, they are surrounded by brackets as if they have become one large array.

In my model my code looks like

```
def bob
  plan_code.split(",").map(&:to_i)
end
```

My results wind up as `[123451, 52354, 12345]`

I'm wondering what I can do to get rid of those brackets and just list the integers?

Comment: ... You're explicitly creating an array with `map`. If that's not what you want, why do it? You already *have* a comma-separated string. What are you trying to do?

Comment: the user inputs the integers with one comma separating them, i would like to display that information with a space between them as well.  (thats ultimately what i'm trying to do here)

Comment: If you're trying to normalize a wonky input, then you need to split on `,`, strip leading and trailing whitespace, and join back up with `, `. IMO you're doing this wrong: at worst you should store it as an actual array, e.g., serialized. If plan codes are a database artifact then you should use a real relationship.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". What is the starting string? You're asking us to guess/imagine what the input is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're storing your values as a string such as `"123, 123"` then there is no point in `map &:to_i`.

You can use `plan_code.split(",").join(", ")` or alternatively `plan_code.gsub(",", ", ")`

Comment: thank you so much! Definitely realized what I was doing wrong based off of your answer.

Comment: Gladly. I think this approach (storing arrays as serialized strings) works for small data sets but you're missing the ability to look at those array values in SQL queries. That's why Rails uses associations/foreign keys. For example say you wanted to search all the `plan_code` records and find which one contains a specific number. You'd need to deserialize every one.